# Strange (?) type mismatch error in this function

Tags: f#

Can someone explain why compiler is giving me this error

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       'a [] -> string
>   but given a
>       'a [] -> 'a []
>   The type 'string' does not match the type ''a []'

on this code snippet:

```
let rotate s: string = 
  [|for c in s -> c|] 
  |> Array.permute (function | 0 -> (s.Length-1) | i -> i-1)
```

while the one below compiles just fine:

```
let s = "string"
[|for c in s -> c|] 
|> Array.permute (function | 0 -> (s.Length-1) | i -> i-1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first snippet defines function `rotate` with return type of `string`.

Try to change it to:

```
let rotate (s: string) = 
  [|for c in s -> c|] 
  |> Array.permute (function | 0 -> (s.Length-1) | i -> i-1)
```

In this form you define a function with one string argument (I suppose that's what you wanted) and inferred return type.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I thought I tried parentheses, but I was wrong.